# Options for editing mpeg video other than MPEG_Streamclip?

Tags: video-editing

I have several MPEG files (technically "MPEG 2" I believe).

I want to do some very simple editing, mostly deleting a few frames here or there.

I do not want to have to re-encode or transcode the video, or do anything else which would decrease the quality of the source.

The only software that I am aware of which does this sort of editing is [MPEG_Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/), but surely there must be others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPEG-2 is subject to license restrictions and royalty payments, so you won't find much in the line of free software to edit MPEG-2 videos.

You can do this sort of editing in QuickTime player with QuickTime Pro, but be aware that MPEG-2 for DVDs uses a complicated compression scheme using key frames and "difference" frames that repeat in a regular pattern (Group of Pictures a.k.a GOP).  You cannot just edit out one frame without re-encoding the rest if you want to play it in a DVD player.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about old QuickTime Pro. I've used that in the past. Fortunately these files will be watched on macs or iOS devices, not DVDs.